# Marking optional member variable as NonNull

Tags: java, option-type, lombok, non-nullable

One of the String member variables of my class is Optional. Does it makes sense to mark it with Lombok annotation @NonNull ?

I would like to ask the same question in case that member variable is Map instead of String. Will the answer change ?

Comment: if you annotate it with `@NonNull`, you will always have to initialize it even if you don't need it. i would think that its not too bad regarding memory usage. same would go for any datatype i'd think

Comment: Didn't get this part - "i would think that its not too bad regarding memory usage". I was thinking that if I making it NonNull will help in avoiding the null check but then going by that logic all the fields (other than primitives) should be marked NonNull. Also marked with NonNull does not mean that it has to be initialized every time ... as I can give default value .. right ? so that  I do not have to initialize it explicitly through builder

Comment: please tell us which `@NonNull` you use. if its lombok's own, then you have another annotation for the default values. regarding the point you didn't understand: if you initialize a variable, you don't need your object will grow in size (some bit/byte). this would mean you would waste memory and the more objects you have, the more memory you would waste

Answer (score 2):

Optional main point is to make fluent API. Field is not and *should not be* a part of API.

What is the difference for you between `Optional<Object> obj` and `Object obj` in fields?

Both of fields could be annotated with `@NotNull`.
Annotating a field with `@NotNull` will give you the same result as annotating an `Optional` but without any extra calls like `ifPresent()`. If you want to use `Optional` to apply chaining operations to a field - you are using `Optional` in a wrong way. There in no reason to use `Optional` in field.

You can read more in openjdk mailing list [optional discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-September/005952.html).

> Having Optional enables to do fluent API [mail.openjdk](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-September/005948.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should mark every `Optional` variable as `@NonNull`.

A variable of Optional type should never be null.  Stuart Marks's [rules about use of Optional](https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/vjug24-session-on-optional/) start with:

1. Never, ever, use null for an Optional variable or return value.

If you write `@NonNull`, then you get tool assistance in ensuring that you do not violate this important rule.

If you do not write `@NonNull`, then you have only your own personal discipline to prevent you from making a mistake, and clients can also make a mistake.

Therefore, you should write `@NonNull`, which serves as machine-readable and machine-checked documentation that the variable should never be null.

This applies not just to fields (member variables), but anywhere than you use `Optional`.

Comment: But also read rule 6: Avoid using Optional in fields, method parameters, and collections.

Comment: Yes, also read the other rules.  However, they are not relevant to the original question.  If you do have a field of Optional type, it should be `@NonNull`.